# Search file *.mp3 in computer

Tags: search, win-universal-app, c++-cx

how search all *.mp3 and *.wav files in my computer? Visual Studio 2015, Universal Windows App, C++/CX. Thanks

Comment: This isn't very clear.  Do you want to search from Visual Studio, or in any way?  If it's the latter, this should be moved to SuperUser.

Comment: Universal windows app - I can use only VS's namespaces for C++/CX, in Win32 it is easy.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to read the user's files (pictures, music, etc.) is to use the `StorageFolder` APIs. If you assume the music is all inside the Music library, you can simply declare the [`musicLibrary` capability](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464936.aspx#general-use_capabilities) and then use [`KnownFolders.MusicLibrary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.musiclibrary.aspx) as the root folder to search. If you really want to search the entire drive, you need to use [`FolderPicker`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.pickers.folderpicker.aspx) and ask the user to select the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search in cmd (console):

```
C:\> where *.mp3
```

Or maybe search in disk *D:* not using *cd* command:

```
C:\> where /R D:\ *.mp3
```

In C++ code(to show the user):

```
#include<windows.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

//Be carefull: dont use: "C:\Folder\", but: "C:\\Folder\\"; In some cases you can write: "C:/Folder/"
string command = "where /R Disk:\\StartSearchFolder\\ filename"; //filename can be "ex.txt", "*.txt", "ex*";
system(command.c_str());
```

Can be helpful use ShellExecute()